# How make sure Aero effect is enabled?

Tags: c#, wpf, winapi, aero, dwm

Is there any api or something that we make sure, Glass effect is already actived? In some codes that i saw, if `DllNotFoundException` throws, then they make sure it's not active or not exists. is there a better or standard way?

This is the solution for Using Aero Effect to [extend glass area in WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748975.aspx).

Comment: For a list of DWM functions, refer to [DWM Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969527.aspx).

Comment: Are you targeting versions of Windows prior to Windows Vista (such as Windows XP)? If not, there's no reason to check for the `DllNotFoundException`. The purpose of that test is not to determine if the Aero effect is *enabled*, but in case the host operating system does not *support* the Desktop Window Manager (DWM) functions responsible for driving the Aero interface.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163435.aspx) it suggests you can detect Glass using [DwmIsCompositionEnabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969518%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> When the status of desktop composition
>   is changed, a WM_DWMCOMPOSITIONCHANGED
>   message is broadcast. There are no
>   parameters telling you if it's being
>   enabled or disabled, so it's up to you
>   to call DwmIsCompositionEnabled if
>   you're interested. The code to do the
>   check is straightforward-the tricky
>   part is deciding how you want your
>   window to look if composition is
>   disabled.

```
[DllImport("dwmapi.dll", PreserveSig = false)]
public static extern bool DwmIsCompositionEnabled();

// Check to see if composition is Enabled
if (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major >= 6 && DwmIsCompositionEnabled())
{
    // enable glass rendering
}
else
{
    // fallback rendering
}
```

However I'm not sure whether you can "Enable Aero" but "Disable Glass" and if so, what the result of the method would be.

Comment: This doesn't really address the same problem that catching `DllNotFoundException` does. On versions of Windows prior to Vista, `dwmapi.dll` does not exist. Trying to call functions from that DLL will therefore fail. You can only call `DwmIsCompositionEnabled` successfully if the host operating system is Vista or later.

Comment: mmmm :-? I think if we migrate it with `Environment.OS.Version >= 6` then it will be complete!

Comment: @Jalal: Indeed, that's the exception-proof way of doing things.

Comment: Apologies - I didn't consider pre-Vista. If you need to target them, checking the OS.Version as you suggest might be the best way.

Comment: Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major >= 6                 this will only be true if vista or newer

Comment: @DannyTuppeny In documentation for the `PreserveSig` field is: "When you set the PreserveSig field to false, the resulting method signature contains a void return type instead of an integer (HRESULT) return type." So, how it is possible that your signature `public static extern bool DwmIsCompositionEnabled()` works (and it works, I tested it :))? According to the documentation, correct form is: `public static extern void DwmIsCompositionEnabled(out bool enabled)`

Comment: @DominikPalo I have no idea =D Someone has asked a similar thing before, but it wasn't really answered! https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/04f36843-ccbc-40e0-8017-8253c4aa139e/how-does-dllimportattributepreservesig-handle-modified-signatures?forum=netfxbcl