# How do I subscribe to an OS-level event raised when DWM composition/Aero Glass is disabled?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, aero, dwm

I'm developing a C# application that supports Windows Aero in the main form.

Some applications that do not support Visual Styles, for example [GoToMeeting](http://www.gotomeeting.com/fec/), disable visual styles and my form is wrongly drawn while GoToMeeting is running (the Aero client area is drawn black).

How could I subscribe to a OS event that is fired when visual styles are disabled? Then I could adjust the client area in my window to be correctly drawn.

Managed and unmanaged solutions are valid for me.

Thanks in advance.

---

**EDIT**: According to Hans's answer, here is the code to manage this event:

```
private const int WM_DWMCOMPOSITIONCHANGED = 0x31e;

[DllImport("dwmapi.dll")]
private static extern void DwmIsCompositionEnabled(ref bool pfEnabled);

protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    if (m.Msg == WM_DWMCOMPOSITIONCHANGED)
    {
        bool compositionEnabled = false;
        DwmIsCompositionEnabled(ref compositionEnabled);

        if (compositionEnabled)
        {
           // composition has been enabled
        }
        else
        {
           // composition has been disabled
        }
    }

    base.WndProc (ref m);
}
```

Comment: Would detecting if Aero is enabled what you're after? If so, this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5114389/how-make-sure-areo-effect-is-enabled

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows sends a message to your toplevel window.  You'd trap it in, say, a WndProc override for a Winforms form.  Listen for WM_DWMCOMPOSITIONCHANGED, message number 0x31e.